# Kryptonians as prehistoric gods & goddesses

Tags: dc, superman

With occasional oblique references to Kryptonians having travelled to other planets in the distant past, is there any connection between the Gods and Goddesses of mythology and empowered Kryptonians in the DC canon?

Comment: Very interesting question, I look forward to the answers!

Comment: If you look at some of the designs in the new Man of Steel movie, you can see designs that wouldn't of been out of place in ancient Egypt or some of the South American cultures. In particular the design of the sentinel that attacks Superman and Lois when they first enter the scout ship is very ancient Egyptian in design.

Comment: Since the Gods & Goddesses of mythology all explicitly exist in the DCU, probably not. There is probably some one-off silver age story somewhere, though.

Comment: In DCU Real god exists specially in Wonder woman stories, so i don't think they are connected .

Answer (score 1):

Certainly not all of them. Some, perhaps. It's worth noting that the Kryptonians were not the only pre-human-history spacefarers in the DCU pre-New-52; it is unlikely they are in the new-52, either.

We also know that some of the Greek pantheon are in fact still present - Wonder Woman and her fellow Amazons have had encounters with the Greek Gods, and they aren't Kryptonians. They are in fact more powerful than Kryptonians. This is true in the Silver Age, Bronze Age, Modern Age, and New 52 comics.

Likewise, several of the Egyptian deities are also known (again from the Wonder Woman comics).